# Can't access SharedPreferences in class that extend Application

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to code global method by extending the `Application` class.
Specifically I'm trying to add 2 method to rapidly access one value that is stored in the `SharedPreferences`.
Unfortunately I can't make the `SharedPreferences` work, here is the code:

```
package postfixcalculator.mattiarubini.com.postfixcalculator;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class PostfixCalculatorExtendApplication extends Application {

    public void ChangePreference (boolean flag){
        //I'm updating the preference file based on the purchase
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.purchase_status), flag);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean RetrievePreferences (){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        /*If the file doesn't exist, I create the file and I'm returned with a false value.
        * Because if the file was not created it's likely to be the first install.
        * If the user acquired the product on the store, it will be able to restore its purchase.*/
        boolean flagPurchase = sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.purchase_status), false);
        return flagPurchase;
    }
}
```

I understand that `getActivity()` doesn't work in an `Activity` but in a `Fragment`, I just don't know what to do in this specific case.
Usually in the `Activity`, to make `SharedPreferences` works, I just need to use the key word `this`.

These are the errors I get:

> Cannot resolve method 'getActivity()'
>
> Cannot resolve method 'getPreferences(int)'

Comment: which activity do you think you are get-ting? What if there are no activities?

Comment: You should get the preferences from the `Context`

Comment: I tried passing the context and it didn't worked

Comment: Application **is** a Context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try getApplicationContext() with getSharedPreferences()

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences .edit();
  editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.purchase_status), flag);
  editor.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution does work, but I'm more incline to use the other one.

Answer (score 1):

I use `getSharedPreferences("Name of preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` in my Application class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using getApplicationContext() instead of getActivity().

Comment: It doesn't work, the problem shift and I get the error: Cannot resolve method 'getPreferences(int)'

Answer (score -1):

Try this for saving shared Preferences:

```
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("key","value").apply();
```

For getting shared preferences value:

```
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    sharedPreferences.getString("key","");
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: It doesn't work I get the error: cannot resolve symbol 'sharedPrefernces'

Comment: you have to declare variable. SharedPreferences sharedPreferences